# How to Customize django bootstrap form

Tags: django, python-3.x, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms, django-templates

I am using boostrap forms but I need to customize it in my design. When I simply write

```
    <form class="firstform" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
```

its showing nice form but I want to edit this form as my design what can be the best way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Django widget tweaks. It’s the best way to decorate and modify your templates in django. https://pypi.org/project/django-widget-tweaks/

You could add attributes, classes etc.

For instance if you would like to insert an input inside your form please add

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}

{{ form.title|add_class:"css_class_1 css_class_2" }}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, would you tell me how can I show error with widget-tweaks as I was getting it with boostrap forms ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [django widget tweaks](https://pypi.org/project/django-widget-tweaks/). This is what I am currently using.
After installing them using`pip install django-widget-tweaks`, and adding to installed_apps, load them using

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
```

in you template and use them like:

```
{% render_field form.some_field | attr:"autfocus" class+="class1 class2" %}
```

which will add attribute 'autofocus' and classes 'class1' and 'class2'